SAP Exception while calling RFC from .NET MVC Framework
I'm using the .NET MVC Framework (v 4.8) to call an RFC function of SAP using RfcDestinationManager from sap.middleware.connector (sapnco.dll and sapnco_util.dll).
The website is hosted on an IIS server with a .NET CLR Version of v4.0.
The issue I'm encountering arises when I call the RFC with the parameter FunctionalLocationID to retrieve SAP notification numbers. While it operates smoothly approximately 80% of the time, occasionally it crashes within the IIS server. Interestingly, there are no exceptions in the code, nor any error traces on the SAP side. The only indication of the issue appears in the Event Viewer of the hosting server.

Below, I've attached screenshots of the encountered errors for further examination.

Log of event "1":
Application: w3wp.exe 
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(System.ExceptionResource) 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection+Enumerator[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
  at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcSessionManager.UpdateSessions(System. Object) 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object) 
  at System.Threadinq.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContextRun(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() 
  at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback(Int32)



Log of event "2":


Log of event "3":




I've checked for exceptions in the code and examined error traces in SAP, but found nothing there. I also attempted to change the application pool configuration.

The problem seems to internal to the SAP RFC library you are using, the stacktrace shows that somewhere in SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcSessionManager.UpdateSession it is iterating over the keys of a dictionary, but that dictionary was modified at the same time, which throws the exception you're seeing. I'm not familiar with the library you're using so I can't explain how/ why that would happen.

Also, please don't post images unless necessary. Text is easier to read (not to mention images are impossible to read for screenreaders) as well as able to be copied. It's explained in more detail here

Please test with the latest SAP .NET Connector library (which version are you using?) or check the bug with SAP Support.

For information, other answers have been posted in your duplicate question at SAP: https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-q-a/sap-exception-while-calling-rfc-from-net-mvc-framework/qaq-p/13666431

Looks like a bug in SAP NCo. If you can reproduce it with the latest NCo version, then you should open a SAP support ticket under component BC-MID-CON-NCO.
